# Not able to compile data with Salstack state file

Tags: networking, automation, salt-stack

I am trying to using Salt state files to configure network devices. I will briefly describe my current setup:
I have pillar ntp.sls file saved as /etc/salt/pillar/ntp.sls and it looks like this:

```
ntp.servers:
  - 11.1.1.1
  - 2.2.2.2
```

Then I have Jinja template saved as /etc/salt/states/ntp/templates/ntp.jinja and looks like this:

```
{%- for server in servers %}
ntp {{ server }}
{%- endfor %}
```

Finally I have state file saved as /etc/salt/states/ntp/init.sls as this:

```
ntp_example:
  netconfig.managed:
    - template_name: salt://ntp/templates/ntp.jinja
    - debug: true
    - servers: {{ salt.pillar.get('ntp.servers') }}
```

I am getting the following error while trying to run the command: sudo salt sw state.sls ntp, where sw is the proxy minion, so here is the error:

```
sw:
    Data failed to compile:

    ID ntp.servers in SLS ntp is not a dictionary
```

Command to get data from pillar is working, command: sudo salt sw pillar.get ntp.servers
Output:

```
sw:
  - 11.1.1.1
  - 2.2.2.2
```

Any suggetions what could be wrong and how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Is `ntp_example` is the only state ID declared in `init.sls`? Error is complaining about an ID called `ntp.servers`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare in `/etc/salt/pillar/ntp.sls` something like:

```
ntp-servers:
  - 11.1.1.1
  - 2.2.2.2
```

and than load these values with:

```
    - servers: {{ salt.pillar.get('ntp-servers') }}
```

The `.` is a directory separator in SaltStack.